# Remove object from an array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component

remove an object from an array is not working properly ,but it add object perfectly

```
const addItem =(selected)=>{
let data = selectedItems ? [...selectedItems] : [];
if (data.length) {
  let index = data.indexOf(selected);
  console.log(index);
  if (index !== -1) {
    data.splice(index, 1);
    setSelectedItems(data);
  } else {
    data.push(selected);
  }
} else {
  data.push(selected);
}
console.log("selected", selectedItems);

setSelectedItems(data);
}
```

render button function add or remove on click it

```
<div className="file-list">
  <MappedElement 
   data={[{ _id: 1 }, { _id: 2 }]}  
   renderElement={(value, index, arr) => { 
   let check=selectedItems.some((obj) => obj._id === value._id); 
   console.log("check", check); 
   return ( 
    <DocumentCard key={index} className={file-list-item ${check ? 
       "active" : ""}} 
    onClick={() => addItem(value, arr, index)} /> ); }} /> 
 </div>
```

Comment: By not working properly what do you mean

Comment: show more code please

Comment: What do `selectedItems` and `selected` look like?

Comment: You should be more specific. splice works just fine, there is something wrong with your code, but unless we see more we can't really help.

Comment: selected is an object like {_id:1} and selectedItems is an state array

Comment: in this case, an error in `data.indexOf(selected)`

Comment: yes it is not updated index value does'nt change it show -1 in console but why?

Comment: [1,2,3].indexOf(1) //working

Comment: each and every time i click on elements same value appear -1 for index

Comment: [{id:1}, {id:2}].indexIf({id:1}) //not working

Comment: i did'nt check simple array

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62152660/9014560

Comment: let data = selectedItems ? [...selectedItems] : [];
if (data.length) {
  let index = data.indexOf(selected);// -1
  console.log(index);
  if (index !== -1) {
    data.splice(index, 1); //false because -1
    setSelectedItems(data); //add element in array
  } else {
    data.push(selected); //add element in array
  }
} else {
  data.push(selected); //add element in array
}
console.log("selected", selectedItems);

setSelectedItems(data); //update state

Comment: Imran please update your question if this last comment contains an updated version of the code you have up here.

Comment: why not use inlcudes and filter to remove the item?

Comment: Junius `includes` won't work here because he's saying it's an array of objects.

Answer (score 1):

For a `selectedItems` array that looks like:

```
const selectedItems = [
    { _id: 1, /* other fields */ },
    { _id: 2, /* other fields */ },
    { _id: 3, /* other fields */ },
    /* other objects */
];
```

And a `selected` object that looks like:

```
const selected = { _id: 1 };
```

In order to perform the desired behavior, which is: *if the element exists, remove it, else, add it*, you can write the following:

```
// copy selected items with a fail-safe empty array
const data = selectedItems ? [...selectedItems] : [];
// find index of selected element
const removalIndex = data.findIndex(({ _id }) => (_id === selected._id));
// if selected element exists in data array, remove it
if (removalIndex !== -1) {
    data.splice(removalIndex, 1);
}
// if selected element doesn't exist in data array, add it
else {
    data.push(selected);
}
// update selected elements
setSelectedItems(data);
```

**NOTE:** if your array of selected items contains duplicates, meaning multiple objects that contain the same value for `_id`, then this approach will be removing only the first instance of those. If you want to remove all of them, you'll have to use a loop or recursivity.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
const addItem =(selected)=>{
let data = selectedItems ? [...selectedItems] : [];
if (data.length) {
  let index = data.findIndex(value => value._id === selected._id)ж
  console.log(index);
  if (index !== -1) {
    data.splice(index, 1);
  } else {
    data.push(selected);
  }
} else {
  data.push(selected);
}
console.log("selected", selectedItems);

setSelectedItems(data);
}
```

Comment: not working it remove element but when i click on 1 it remove 2 and remove 1

Comment: <div className="file-list">
        <MappedElement
          data={[{ _id: 1 }, { _id: 2 }]}
          renderElement={(value, index, arr) => {
            let check = selectedItems.some((obj) => obj._id === value._id);
            console.log("check", check);
            return (
              <DocumentCard
                key={index}
                className={`file-list-item ${check ? "active" : ""}`}
                onClick={() => addItem(value, arr, index)}
              />
            );
          }}
        />
      </div>

Comment: this is the button which call this function

Comment: why do you call setSelectedItems two times?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably in `indexOf` method you're using.

You can not use this to find objects in your array.

There are several options you can use. You can use find or findIndex and pass a callback to find an object by the specified (preferably unique property of the object).

Example

```
let found = data.findIndex(item => item.id === selected.id);
```